# Напечатать номер элемента списка и номер элемента в списке, который имеет максимальное значение

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, список

Дан список списков, состоящий из целых чисел.
Напечатать номер элемента списка и номер элемента в
списке, который имеет максимальное значение.

Не работает на разных задаваемых величинах списка и элементов. 
Запутался в конце программы, нужно чтобы правильно выводило максимальные значения.

Вот мой код:

```
n = int(input("Введите количество списков: "))
m = int(input("Введите количество элементов в каждом списке: "))
lst = []
maxi=0
maxj=0
for i in range(n):
    lst.append([])
    for j in range(m):
        r = int(input("Введите число: "))
        lst[i].append(r)
        
        
maxi= max(lst)
max1 = len (lst)
u = max(maxi)
print ("Исходный список списков: ",lst)
print ("Номер элемента списка,который имеет максимальное значение: ",max1 )
print ("Номер элемента в списке,который имеет максимальное значение:",maxi.index(u))
```

Результат работы программы:

```
    Введите количество списков: 3
Введите количество элементов в каждом списке: 2
Введите число: 334543
Введите число: 3453
Введите число: 2
Введите число: 3534346
Введите число: 3
Введите число: 4
Исходный список списков:  [[334543, 3453], [2, 3534346], [3, 4]]
Номер элемента списка,который имеет максимальное значение:  3
Номер элемента в списке,который имеет максимальное значение:  1
```

Comment: Номер или индекс? Номер обычно начинается с 1, а индекс с 0. `Напечатать номер элемента списка и номер элемента в списке, который имеет максимальное значение` напечатать номер какого элемента? Там точно нет опечатки? Мб, имеется ввиду напечатать максимальный элемент в списке и его номер?

Comment: Нужен именно номер, снизу правильно составили суть программы, только он печатает индекс, нужен номер, то есть каким то образом добавить единицу

Comment: Что значит `каким-то образом`? :) Находите место добавления или вывода индекса и добавляете туда `+ 1`, все :)

Comment: Да, всё, нашел, спасибо :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import pprint

#                        vvv
lists =[[1,2,3], [22,23, 999, 24,25], [33,34]]

listAll = [ [[i,j,s]  for j,s in enumerate(s1)]  for i,s1 in enumerate(lists)]
pprint.pprint(listAll)
"""
[[[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 3]],
 [[1, 0, 22], [1, 1, 23], [1, 2, 999], [1, 3, 24], [1, 4, 25]],
 [[2, 0, 33], [2, 1, 34]]]
"""

rez = listAll[0][0]
m   = listAll[0][0][2]

for i in listAll:
    for j in i:
        if j[2] > m:
            rez = j
            m = j[2]

print(rez)
[1, 2, 999]
```

`listAll` список списков. Каждый элемент которого содержит:

`s` - элемент входного списка списков (1,2,3,22,23,999,24,25,33,34)

`i` - индекс списка в котором каждый элемент (например: элемент `1` находится в списке с индексом `0`, а элемент `999` находится в списке с индексом `1`)

`j` - индекс каждого элемента в списке с индексом `i` (например: элемент `1` находится в списке `i - [1, 2, 3]` с индексом `0`, а элемент `999` находится в списке `[22, 23, 999, 24, 25]` с индексом `2`)

Сделайте импорт `import pprint`  и выведите на печать `listAll` после расчета `pprint.pprint(listAll)`

Comment: Как прибавить единицу к индексу? Мне нужен номер

Comment: Не понял вопрос. Напишите что вы хотите получить, глядя на мой пимер.

Comment: Я нашел уже, где можно прибавить.Спасибо
То есть мне нужно было не индекс элемента, а его номер
То есть индекс начинается с 0, а номер с 1

Comment: Можно обьяснить, что делает эта строка ?
listAll = [ [[i,j,s]  for j,s in enumerate(s1)]  for i,s1 in enumerate(lists)]

Comment: я постараля объяснить, посмотрите обновление.

Answer (score 0):

Вы не правильно используете функцию `max`, и для получения индекса элемента удобней использовать функцию `enumerate`:

```
lists = [[334543, 3453], [2, 3534346], [3, 4]]

max_index = -1
max_value = -1

for i, lst in enumerate(lists):
    mx = max(lst)
    if mx>max_value:
        max_index = i
        max_value = mx


print(max_index, max_value)
```

Вывод:

```
1 3534346
```